# Is there any extension in vscode to generate a stepdefinition file in java from a .feature file?

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

I want that when i create my .feature file, i want some extension in vscode which generates a step definition file in java. I have seen many such extensions for js but not for java.

I tried downloading many extensions but no one worked for java.

Answer (score -1):

Please. Here you are. This plugin supports it.

> Features
>
> - Autocomplete of Gherkin steps
> - Go to step definition
> - **Generate step definition**
> - Syntax highlighting
> - Formatting (pretty printing)
> - Language support
>
>   - C#/SpecFlow
>   - Go/Godog - help needed
>   - **Java**
>   - JavaScript
>   - PHP
>   - Python/Behave
>   - Ruby
>   - Rust
>   - TypeScript

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CucumberOpen.cucumber-official#generate-step-definition

[It works. I have checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIMo0.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33751024)

Comment: IMO the only value of answers in such kind of questions is in links pointing some specific extensions. Copying and pasting of their description has limited or none value.